dotnet publish for ASP.NET Core MVC doesn't correctly handle wwwroot folder
I have a simple github actions deployments:
    build:
      ..
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v4

        - name: Set up .NET Core
          uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
          with:
            dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}

        - name: Build with dotnet
          working-directory: ./${{ matrix.value }}
          run: dotnet build --configuration Release

        - name: dotnet publish
          working-directory: ./${{ matrix.value }}
          run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/${{ matrix.value }}/${{ env.APP_NAME }}

        - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
          uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
          with:
            name: .net-ui
            path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/${{ matrix.value }}/${{ env.APP_NAME }}

when in the next job I'm going to deploy these changes via:
  - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
    id: deploy-to-webapp
    uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
    with:
      app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_APP_NAME }}
      package: ${{ env.AZURE_APP_PACKAGE_PATH }}

UPDATE: I just noticed that wwwroot folder with css and js files are copied to azure. My server side files placed in the C:\home\site\wwwroot:
C:\home\site\wwwroot>ls
Humanizer.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.dll
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll
..
web.config
wwwroot

and inner wwwroot folder is:
C:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot>ls     # pay attention on doubled `wwwroot`
UI.styles.css
css
favicon.ico
js
lib

however lib folder doesn't have all files:
C:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\lib>ls    
bootstrap
jquery
jquery-validation
jquery-validation-unobtrusive

where locally I have also microsoft folder with signalr dependencies (dependency files themself are not under git though, but microsoft folder is under the git => all this behavior is default though). I assume I need to restore this somehow.
Another strange part is that some files presented locally (/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js), are not copied on the azure server even though the folder where they are placed has been copied:
C:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\lib\jquery>ls
LICENSE.txt     # pay attention no "dist" folder

Given the above, these files are not visible in the browser and gives this error:
    GET https://azureapp.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
    [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 351ms

How can I fix handling static files (css/js)? Any help would be appreciated.

So you want to access the static files ?What is the version of your app?

@Harshitha, I simply want to have access to wwwroot folder from my application in the azure app services deployment.

Ok..will check and let you know.you want to access wwwroot folder which is under site/wwwroot/wwwroot right?

@Harshitha, well in this case I'm not sure, I would expect that no doubled wwwroot folder will exist and all (binaries and static) files will be placed just in a single top level wwwroot, so probably my first question is whether it's normal or not? And if it's normal, then why in the nested wwwroot folder I don't see all static files that I have locally

no..all the static files will be deployed wwwroot/wwwroot folder itself,because in local you can see the wwwroot file.If you dont want them under double wwwroot folder place them in the application root directory.

@Harshitha, that is what I suspected too (even though it looks very strange to me), but in any case, then why not all wwwroot files I have locally, actually added to azure app services?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The issue is with your yml file dotnet publish step.
My dotnet publish looks like below:
- name: dotnet publish
run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp


All the static files which are under wwwroot local folder are handled with the dotnet publish and included by default in the deployed folder.

My .csproj looks simple and is default.


<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>


Push the root folder (where you have Controllers) of the application to GitHub .


My complete Workflow file:
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - CoreMVC20Sep

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.x'

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write 

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app
      
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_********** }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_********** }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_********** }}

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'CoreMVC20Sep'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .          


I am able to see the dist folder when I run dotnet publish command in local as well.


Deployment:

Able to access the files which are under site/wwwroot/wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist folder.


How can I fix handling static files (css/js)?

Check this MSDoc  to access any static files from a specific folder.

not really (it's unrelated to github actions), the issue that I have excluded dist folders from git, so these folders were excluded from dotnet publish output

but in any case, thanks!
